# UIImageView+AFNetworking.h file not found

Tags: ios

I've already import AFNetworking using CocoaPod, it's already showed on my project, but when I build, it show error

[image]

Please point me somethings.

Comment: `#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you added AFNetworking using cocoapods, you should be able to use it in 2 ways:

1) You use bridging header - then inside the bridging header you import it in the obj-c style -- `#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>` -- and you're ready to go

2) You add AFNetworking as a framework. Your Podfile should look like this (just an example, notice uncommented line with `use_frameworks!`):

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'image-swift-networking' do
pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

In this case you won't need the bridging header but you will need to import AFNetworking right in your swift file (`import AFNetworking`).

Now you should be able to use it without problems:

```
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
image.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
image.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Its_something.png")!)
self.view.addSubview(image)
```

Comment: Ok, I use it as a framework, so I delete the .h file, but it say bringing-header.h does not exist, so how to solve this problem?

Comment: Go into your target build settings and search for `Bridging-Header.h` phrase. The line it finds you can delete, and then it should compile without problems.